# Replicating Page insights overview box with the ability to change the date range

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

When you go to the facebook insights url in the business manager (https://business.facebook.com/[sitename]/insights/?business_id=[business_id]) you can see an overview of (page likes, post reach and engagement) that says Showing data from 05/21/2015 - 05/27/2015

Example Image: http://imgur.com/wVs5xli

I want to be able to replicate the above or be able to change the date range.

I am unable to find a way to be able to change the date range, even using the API endpoints https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights#metrics

I found ways to get the daily data for some of the metrics. Page likes
{object-id}/insights/page_fans I believe I am supposed to just store the information locally into my own database then I can filter by any date range.

That's the first box, the second box "Post Reach" I believe I need to use the post {page-id}/posts endpoint to get all the posts in the date range i want. Then manually tally all the information but I cant find the page that documents the information {page-id}/posts end point. So I can't actually find the metrics in that endpoint. Maybe its the posts-insights endpoint but that doesn't seem to work.

I found this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ and I see the posts-insights endpoint but it does not seem to work.
{page-id}/posts_insights?since=2015-05-10&until=2015-05-26 returns

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1
  }
}
```

The 3rd box is probably similar to the second box but maybe its the fact I can't get the information from posts-insights. Anyone have an example of that posts-insights outputs or any information that could help me in figuring out this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured most of this out the endpoints needed are:

```
Page likes: [object-id]/insights/page_fans
Total Reach: [object-id]/insights/page_impressions_unique
post reach: [object-id]/insights/page_posts_impressions_unique
likes, comments, and shares [object-id]/insights/page_positive_feedback_by_type
```